# Why are water softeners a domestic installation?

Tags: plumbing, water-softener

I live in a south England region with very hard water, and some years ago I bought a water softener, which has made a big difference by eliminating scale buildup around plugholes etc. However, these softeners are quite expensive and do not last forever.

Why is water softening something that has to be installed domestically, in each home? Would it not be more efficient for the supplier to soften the domestic water before sending it down the pipe? Or are there practical reasons why this would not work? (For example, is it impossible to stop the water picking up more mineral content within the pipe?)

(I realise this is a "general" question and not an individual DIY problem but this seems to be the most relevant StackExchange site...)

Comment: Some are fitted in schools and hotels to reduce boiler servicing costs.

Comment: Some people like hard water for drinking. The house I grew up in had the cold water line to _one_ bathroom plumbed _before_ the softener so there was hard water there because that's how the owner liked it (we rented). All other interior plumbing went through the softener. Mineral water & sparkling water are pretty big things throughout Europe (<>UK, I know), so why remove the water for the whole city? Force even more people to buy bottled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Water "hardness" varies widely between municipalities, and many homes are on different wells even within cities. Even where the city provides water it's a matter of personal taste whether soft water is desired. I have friends with water hard enough to render soap practically useless in the shower, and that's how they like it<sup>1</sup>.

Plus, a good portion of water is used for outdoor purposes such as irrigation. It would often be expensive and wasteful to condition water for such use. It can also be detrimental to deposit residual salt during irrigation and other outdoor use.

Who decides when water is hard enough to require a city-wide softener? Who decides how soft it should be made? It's hard enough deciding how much to spend on schools. Try getting them to agree on water softness, and then pay for it. No thanks.

<sub>1. Freaking nutjobs, they are.</sub>

Comment: In addition to @isherwood's valid comments, "soft" water often has salts from the softening process in the water, which is generally considered unhealthy to drink in anything more than small quantities to prevent extra sodium intake.  Hence, often the consumable water cold line (kitchen faucets, refrigerator taps, etc.) is tapped off before the softener so it doesn't have the salts in it.

Comment: Hardness can vary even within a municipality: water in the city where I live is provided from multiple wells within the city and from a regional supplier outside the city. The sources mix in a semi-uncontrolled way within the system. Hardness varies widely at the sources, though I will note that the city is in fact pursuing a softening project at a certain well where hardness is exceptionally high. This well had been taken offline for a few years because of resident complaints.

Comment: Chiming in here, softened water is not good for irrigation...too much left over salt.  I have 2 lines coming out of my pump house, one is for irrigation (very hard water) and the other is for the house after being softened.   We also have an RO filter for a couple of select faucets in the kitchen to remove the residual salt.